# Is there an implicit assumption that each quantum well contains a single electron only?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is it true that each electron can be represented as a quantum well?

I had believed that each energy level was able to contain multiple states and each states were able to hold multiple electrons.

Comment: What do you mean by "representing an electron as a quantum well"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an assumption, actually. In quantum mechanics, we learn that there are (at least) two kinds of particles which behave differently in their ability to share states. It can be shown that one of these, known as bosons, prefer to be in the same state. The other, known as fermions, are forbidden from occupying the same state. (This is known as the Pauli exclusion principle.) Electrons are fermions. They may still fit into the same energy level if that energy level has multiple available states--for instance, electrons have spin, so they can fit two electrons in a given state as long as they keep their spins oppositely aligned.